# How to solve a quintic polynomial equation?

Tags: polynomials, roots

I know that not all quintics are solvable. But how do I identify the class of solvable ones?

Comment: The ones with at least one rational root can be identified quickly using the rational root theorem and then the remaining quartic always has an exact solution in radicals. Beyond that, I'm sure someone else will answer with deeper theory.

Comment: You have to find out the so-called galois-group over $\mathbb Q$ of the given quintic. This is not so easy by hand, but for example PARI/GP and GAP can identify it. The quintic can be solved by radicals if and only if the galois group is solvable.

Comment: First check, whether the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$. If no, the quintic can be solved by radicals because polynomials with degree less than $5$ can always be solved by radicals. If yes, you have to find out the galois-group.

Comment: It also depends on what you need the solution for. If it's for practical purposes, the numerical methods are usually better (like the Newton's method) and they work for any polynomial equation

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you haven't reached that part of Galois theory yet, there is still a "*simple*" elementary way to test if a quintic is solvable. First, reduce it to depressed form (without the $x^4$ term).

---

**I. Method 1:**

*Theorem* (by Watson, 1930s): "Given an *irreducible* quintic with rational coefficients,

$$x^5 + 10c x^3 + 10d x^2 + 5 e x + f = 0\tag1$$

If the sextic,

$$3125p^6 - 625(3c^2 + e)p^4 + 25(15c^4 + 8c d^2 - 2c^2e + 3e^2 - 2d f)p^2 + 
  p\sqrt{D} + (-25c^6 - 40c^3d^2 - 16d^4 + 35c^4e + 28c d^2e - 11c^2e^2 + 
      e^3 - 2c^2d f - 2d e f + c f^2)=0$$

with discriminant $D$,

$$D=-3200c^3d^2e^2 - 2160d^4e^2 + 6400c^4e^3 + 5760c d^2e^3 - 2560c^2e^4 + 
  256e^5 + 5120c^3d^3f + 3456d^5f - 11520c^4d e f - 10080c d^3e f + 
  4480c^2d e^2f - 640d e ^3f + 3456c^5f^2 + 2640c^2d^2f^2 - 1440c^3e f^2 + 
  360d^2e f^2 + 160c e^2f^2 - 120c d f^3 + f^4$$

has a root $p$ such that $p^2$ is rational, then $(1)$ is a solvable quintic."

See "*[Commentary on an unpublished lecture by G. N. Watson on solving the quintic](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.117.6872)*" by Bruce Berndt. This is easily implemented in *Mathematica* and is useful when dealing with parametric quintics.

---

(***Edit: July 17, 2023***.) As asked by user [dxiv](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/291201/dxiv), Watson's method in Berndt's paper has a stumbling block since it has division by $p$ (the sextic root). So what happens when $p=0$? I found the solution was to bring Watson's method to its logical conclusion and ***construct the quartic resolvent***, then check if there were any cancellation of divisors. Fortunately there was.

Thus, given the quintic,

$$x^5 + 10c x^3 + 10d x^2 + 5 e x + f = 0\tag1$$

if the coefficients obey,

$$-25c^6 - 40c^3d^2 - 16d^4 + 35c^4e + 28c d^2e - 11c^2e^2 + e^3 - 2c^2d f - 2d e f + c f^2 = 0$$

then the constant term of Watson's sextic resolvent is zero, hence its root $p=0$. (*Note*: Since the condition is just a quadratic in $f$, it is quite easy to find solvable quintics by finding $c,d,e$ such that $f$ is rational.)

More aesthetically, if $c\neq 0$, the quintic's coefficients form a "square",

$$\big(c^3 + d^2 - c e\big) \big(25 c^4 - 10 c^2 e + e^2 + 16 c d^2\big) = \big(c^2 d + d e - c f\big)^2\tag2$$

The solution of $(1)$ is then,

$$x = z_1^{1/5}+z_2^{1/5}+z_3^{1/5}+z_4^{1/5}$$

where the $z_i$ are the four roots of the two quadratics in $z$,

$$z^2+\frac12\left(f\pm\sqrt{-16 c^5 + 20 c^3 e + 16 d^2 e - 4 c e^2 - 8 c d f + f^2}\right)z-c^5=0$$

which are purely in the coefficients of the quintic.

**Example**. Let,

$$x^5 + 10x^3 + 110x^2 - 15x + 478 = 0$$

which obeys $(2)$ so Watson's sextic has root $p=0$. Then the two quadratics are,

$$z^2+\left(239+95\sqrt5\right)z-1=0$$
$$z^2+\left(239-95\sqrt5\right)z-1=0$$

The real root of the quintic is then,

$$\qquad x = z_1^{1/5}+z_2^{1/5}+z_3^{1/5}+z_4^{1/5} = -4.509908339\dots$$

**P.S.** The case $p=0$ in fact is special. More on that in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129655/on-solvable-quintics-and-septics).

---

**II. Method 2:**

If you are in a rush and just want to determine if a particular equation is solvable, you can find the order of its ***Galois group*** using this online [Magma calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/). For example, to test the *solvable* but irreducible $x^5-5x+12=0$, copy and paste the command,

> Z := Integers();
> P < x > := PolynomialRing(Z);
> f :=  x^5-5*x+12;
> G, R := GaloisGroup(f);
> G;

One then finds the order is $10$, hence that quintic is solvable. ***All*** groups with order $<60$ are, though there are solvable groups with order $>60$.

**Note:** Don't forget the *asterisk* between the numerical coefficient and the variable, like this: **5*x**.

---

**III. Addendum on Method 1** (by Oscar Lanzi):

We can reduce Method 1 to a simple rational root test by "root squaring".

Render the sextic equation above as

$\alpha p^6 + \beta p^4 + \gamma p^2 + p\sqrt{D} + \delta = 0$

Separate the odd degree term from the even degree ones:

$\alpha p^6 + \beta p^4 + \gamma p^2 + \delta = - p\sqrt{D}$

And square.  Only even powers of $p$ now appear so we have a polynomial equation in $p^2$::

$(\alpha p^6 + \beta p^4 + \gamma p^2 + \delta)^2=p^2D$

$\alpha^2(p^2)^6 + 2\alpha \beta(p^2)^5 + (2\alpha \gamma + \beta^2)(p^2)^4 + 2(\alpha \delta + \beta \gamma)(p^2)^3 + (2\beta \delta + \gamma^2)(p^2)^2 + (2 \gamma \delta - D)(p^2) + \delta^2 = 0$

You may then apply the standard rational root test to this equation.  If it passes, the conditions for solvability of the quintic are satisfied.

Comment: Is the condition in method $(1)$ both necessary and sufficient?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: Yes, there is actually a relatively simple transformation that transforms this 1930s sextic to the modern version derived by Dummit in his well-known paper.

Comment: Minor point here: when you say all groups with order $<60$ are solvable, do you mean $\le 60$?

Comment: @OscarLanzi: Strictly $<60$. Note that $A(5)$ has order $=60$ and [is unsolvable](http://galoisdb.math.uni-paderborn.de/groups?deg=5).

Comment: OK.  What prompted me to ask was, you did not include order=60 in your discussion.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Thanks for *method 1* and the reference. I was wondering how that works when the rational root is $p=0$. Tried to follow it in the paper, but *step 1* on page 22 has an implicit assumption that $M \ne 0$. Guess it was too trivial a case to even mention, though it's not immediately obvious (to me) why. FWIW this *can* happen e.g. for the solvable quintic with [$c=-5$, $d=-10$, $e=5$, $f=60$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-25C%5E6-40C%5E3D%5E2-16D%5E4%2B35C%5E4E%2B28C+D%5E2E-11C%5E2E%5E2%2BE%5E3-2C%5E2D+F-2D+E+F%2BC+F%5E2+where+C%3D-5%2CD%3D-10%2CE%3D5%2CF%3D60).

Comment: @dxiv When I first read the paper, I also noticed $p=0$ would be tricky. Watson kinda glossed over it, but there is a way around it. I've edited my answer to address your comment. _P.S._ And the case $p=0$ is not trivial at all. In fact, it is a special property of some quintics.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Neat, thank you! Wonder if there is anything remarkable about "my" quintic $z^5-50z^3-100z^2+25z+60$, whose roots are sums of fifth roots of Gaussian integers, first one $(-5(11+2i))^{1/5}$ $+(-5(11-2i))^{1/5}$ $+\bar\omega^2(25(1+2i))^{1/5}$ $+\omega^2(25(1-2i))^{1/5}$  where $\omega=e^{2\pi i/5}$ (verified in [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28-5%2811%2B2i%29%29%5E%281%2F5%29%2B%28-5%2811-2i%29%29%5E%281%2F5%29%2B%28cos%284pi%2F5%29-i+sin%284pi%2F5%29%29%2825%281%2B2i%29%29%5E%281%2F5%29%2B%28cos%284pi%2F5%29%2Bi+sin%284pi%2F5%29%29%2825%281-2i%29%29%5E%281%2F5%29)).

Comment: @dxiv Well, other than sharing the property all quintics with $p=0$ have, there is a further simplification since $-(11+2i)=(1+2i)^3$ so these Gaussian integers also share common factors.