# On the trigonometric roots of some quintics

Tags: trigonometry, roots, closed-form, roots-of-unity

> **I. Cubics**

The cubic 
$$x^3+x^2-2x-1=0$$
and its solution in terms of $\cos(n\pi/7)$ is well-known. A general formula for other primes $\color{blue}{p=6m+1}$ is discussed in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022216/on-the-trigonometric-roots-of-a-cubic).

> **II. Quintics**

We have
$$x^5 + x^4 - 4 x^3 - 3 x^2 + 3 x + 1=0,\quad\quad x =\sum_{k=1}^{2}\,\exp\Bigl(\tfrac{2\pi\, i\, (10^k)}{11}\Bigr)\\
x^5 + x^4 - 12 x^3 - 21 x^2 + x + 5=0,\quad\quad x =\sum_{k=1}^{6}\,\exp\Bigl(\tfrac{2\pi\, i\, (6^k)}{31}\Bigr)$$

and so on as in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1996552/any-more-cyclic-quintics). The general form for prime $\color{blue}{p=10m+1}$ is 
$$x^5 + x^4 - 4m x^3 +a x^2 + bx + c=0$$
for some integer $a,b,c$

> **Q:** Can we express $a,b,c$ as a polynomial in $p$ and some specified Diophantine equation $F(u,v)$ just like in the [cubic case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022216/on-the-trigonometric-roots-of-a-cubic)?