# About roots for 5 degree polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am looking for examples where the roots of a 5 degree  polynomial in $Q[x]$ cannot be expressed in terms of radicals (that part is easy to acchieve, there are a lot of examples) but they CAN be expressed in terms of something else.  In other words, I am looking for an example where I can see the roots in an explicit way and where we can explicitly see that they are not in terms of radicals.

Comment: I believe you mean 5th degree integer/rational polynomial (definitely not *real* polynomial)

Comment: "Radicals" as in square roots only, or $n$th roots?

Comment: you might like these  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1996552/any-more-cyclic-quintics

Comment: Here's a paper you may find interesting: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.0955.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Well, since the OP never edited...

$x^5-\pi$ is a perfectly valid example as $\sqrt[5]\pi$ is a root which is transcendental