# Dot Product of Vectors of Roots of Unity

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-numbers, cyclotomic-polynomials, cyclotomic-fields, coxeter-groups

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $i$ be the usual complex number such that $i^2=-1$.

Let $\zeta = \exp(\frac{\pi}{n} i)$, $v = [1,\zeta,\zeta^2,\ldots,\zeta^{n-1}]$. Given $J \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$, let $u_J$ be the vector in $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that its $k^{th}$ entry is $-1$ if $k \in J$ and $1$ otherwise.

What is the dot product of $v$ and $u_J$?

I guess this is a relatively simple question and well understood in Number Theory (specifically cyclotomic fields?) and wondered if someone can point me to some citable references or useful information. This happens to have come up in a Coxeter Group context (projecting the vertices of a regular $n$-cube onto a Coxeter plane) and I would not be surprised if this is something Coxeter himself or someone with similar interests studied this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If $J$ is completely arbitrary I doubt much can be said about that sum. But note that since $\sum \zeta^k = 0$, you sum is $-2\sum_{k\in J}\zeta^k$.

Comment: nice outcome when $J$ is a subgroup of the multiplicative group (of $\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$), which has $ \phi(n)$ elements. This was the approach of Gauss; we get integer coefficient polynomials. Many examples in https://www.google.com/books/edition/Tafeln_complexer_Primzahlen/wt7lgfeYqMQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=reuschle++tafeln+complexer+primzahlen&pg=PR1&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=reuschle%20%20tafeln%20complexer%20primzahlen&f=false

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you for this. The reference looks useful. Its interesting that you mention the subgroups of  ℤ/ℤ - I wonder if something like the smallest subgroup containing it might be controlling the magnitude of the answer.

Comment: a few chapters on the Gauss method, very good author: http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/cox_galois_Gaussian_periods.pdf   I wrote up lots of examples of the type constructing polynomials  with all roots real and sums of cosines   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2022216/on-the-trigonometric-roots-of-a-cubic/2022887#2022887  =====  
  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1996552/any-more-cyclic-quintics